# if condition with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to do this if(status==0) then only where condition is run and print only related to status==0 record.And when status==1 come then it bypass the where clause and print both data for status 0 and 1. I don't know how to build a query for this. Please help me in this.

**my model code**

```
 function listing(){    
 $admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
 $query = $this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status')
         ->from('student_info')
         ->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id)
         ->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id')
         ->get();
 return $query->result();
 }
```

This code work properly and print separate data whose status 0 or 1.

Only admin_id = 1 contain Status = 1, other id's contain 0 status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        function listing(){    
            $admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
            $query = $this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status')
                ->from('student_info')                    
                ->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id')
                ->where("student_info.admin_id = IF (admin.status = 0, $admin_id, '>-1'")
                ->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

Comment: Oh one extra equal to (=) sign was there. Can you try the edited answer

Comment: A slight change. Can you try again with the newly edited answer.

Comment: sorry sir this is also not working:
Error Number: 1064

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your kindness and time. I got the answer by only doing this
 $this->db->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id);
 $this->db->or_where('admin.status < 1');

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with the following code...

```
<?php
function listing($status)
{     
    $this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status');
    $this->db->from('student_info');
    if($status==0) 
    {
        $this->db->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id);
    }
    $this->db->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
?>
```

Comment: It gives error : syntax error, unexpected T_IF in D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\models\student.php on line 17

Comment: sorry sir but it still gives an error : 
 unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: what is your php version ??

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your kindness and time. I got the answer by only doing this
 $this->db->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id);
 $this->db->or_where('admin.status < 1');

Comment: ohh .. great, I'm also looking for `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` , i think it is due to lower php version..

Answer (score 0):

It solves my problem..

```
function listing()  
 {  
$admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
$this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status');
$this->db->from('student_info');
$this->db->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id');
$this->db->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id);
$this->db->or_where('admin.status < 1');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    function listing($status)
    {     
if($status == 0){
$this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status');
        $this->db->from('student_info');
        $this->db->where('student_info.admin_id',$admin_id);
        $this->db->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}else{
$this->db->select('student_info.*,admin.status');
        $this->db->from('student_info');
        $this->db->join('admin','admin.admin_id = student_info.admin_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}


    }
    ?>
```